# The terminal process "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command npm run watch" terminated with exit code: 1

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I cloned that [github repository](https://github.com/4a1c0/voice-comments) on vscode, when i use f5 to run the extension i get displayed the error in the title, i did searched for the exit code error but didn't find a solution for it.

Comment: It really depends on which extension repo you cloned. Edit the question please, so that no one needs to guess.

Comment: Oh sorry thought it was a general problem, linked